# Manual Partitioning Help

Tags: installation, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I want to tri-boot my HP G6 laptop.

i wana install windows, ubuntu and linux kali using **UEFI**..

i want to install them making manual partitions...
First m installing windows...For that following partition were created -

1. Windows boot parttion
2. A 100 MB EFI partition
3. and a 300 MB Recovery partition

Now m installing Ubuntu 13.04 and then Linux Kali using UEFI boot..

While doing manual partition i created a ext4 partition for ubuntu.

So my qustion is, - as windows has already created 100 MB EFI partition do i have create again efi partition for ubuntu and then again another efi partition for linux kali?

And secondly, Ubuntu requires a SWAP partition,
so do i need to create again another swap partition while installing linux kali?

Please help..

Answer (score 1):

No, you should not try to create another EFI system partition.  You do not have to create another swap partition either; they can both use the same one.

Answer (score 0):

Windows has specific requirements which you need to do first.

Microsoft suggested partitions including reserved partition for gpt & UEFI:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744301%28WS.10%29.aspx

Older Windows info on gpt - 2008 updated 2011

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463525.aspx

Windows technical info on gpt and GUIDs

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/aa365449

Order on drive is important:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Reserved_Partition

You may want a slight larger efi partition of 300MB-500MB as every install's boot loader goes into the efi partition and later you may want additional files in there also.

You do not need two swaps but cannot hibernate as that data is written into swap. But hibernation is not normally suggested when multiple booting.

You also may want a shared data partition as NTFS for all 3 systems or an ext3 data partition for Linux data to share.

Comment: KK.. But what if i install Ubuntu first and then Windows?
   What difference will be there?
Would i get grub to select which OS to load?